# I have the following typerror 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, list, integer, typeerror, python-itertools

I have the following code:

```
count_by_week=df[df['institution_id']==1].groupby(['group_ident','Year','Week'],observed=True, as_index=True)['activity_id','Teacher_ID','school_subject'].nunique()
g=[2332136, 2192823, 2192825]
Y21=[2021]
Y22=[2022]
l21=list(range(30,53,1))
l22=list(range(1,10,1))
for i in g:
    lw=list(itertools.product(i,Y21,l21))+list(itertools.product(i,Y22,l22))
    count_by_week.loc[count_by_week.index.isin(lw),:]
```

and I got the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-426-f18510fd39e9> in <module>
     11 l22=list(range(1,10,1))
     12 for i in g:
---> 13     lw=list(itertools.product(i,Y21,l21))+list(itertools.product(i,Y22,l22))
     14     count_by_week.loc[count_by_week.index.isin(lw),:]

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I tried many ways to get the output with no result, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What did you expect to be the value of `i` in the line which has the error?

Comment: The for loop should iterate on the the items in the list g and find the list of indexes in lw list then return the corresponding datapoints from the count_by_week DataFrame

Comment: Yes, but what did you expect to be the value of `i` in the expression `itertools.product(i,Y21,l21)`?

Comment: a list of indexes for count_by_week which shoud be as following:``` [(2192823, 2021, 30),
 (2192823, 2021, 31),
 (2192823, 2021, 32),
 (2192823, 2021, 33),
 (2192823, 2021, 34),
 (2192823, 2021, 35),
 (2192823, 2021, 36),
 (2192823, 2021, 37),
 (2192823, 2021, 38),
 (2192823, 2021, 39),
 (2192823, 2021, 40),
 (2192823, 2021, 41),
 (2192823, 2021, 42),
...
```

Comment: Well that's not what `i` is. It's just a number. So you are calling `itertools.product` with a number as argument. But it expects lists or other iterables as arguments.

Comment: ```i``` here is only the item of the group which is the first level of the multindex. I have the weeks counted in year 2021 which is from wee=32 up to week=52, then the weeks in 2022 which is from week 1 to week=9, I haven't been able to find another way to creat a list of tuples for the indexes except this way..

Comment: I think you are asking a simple version of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191937/python-itertools-with-fix-parameters. So change `itertools.product(i, ...)` to `itertools.product([i], ...)`.